# "They thought of us as parents'"

Tags: punctuation

I'm writing a poem. No matter how much I study, I'm often tripped up in understanding when to use an apostrophe. Hope someone can confirm this is correct.

> They thought of us as parents'
> Our inadequacies safely disguised...

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to tell us why you think an apostrophe is needed?

Answer (score 4):

You use an apostrophe for (most) possessives, and for contractions.

You would use an apostrophe if you were writing about your parents' friends - the friends of your parents. If just one parent were involved you could write about a parent's friend. So I don't see how an apostrophe shows up here in your poem.

I assume  the speaker is trying to say  that they thought of us as their parents, so did not recognize the ways in which we were inadequate, since children often don't see parental inadequacy.

If so, I would use a comma

> They thought of us as parents, our inadequacies safely disguised...